# Getting File name from String in Shell Script

Tags: shell, sh

I need to get the name of the file (IN_INK_GOOGLE_20200519.dat) in below string . I want to do it using shellscript. Also, as filename regex conditions are - should start with **IN_INK** & end with **.dat** and if it matches more than once, only one match or first match should print. is it possible? ,

echo  "-sIN.GOOGLE.IN.INK.INNK.INACC\n-i/am/ft/data/INK/out/GOOGLE_INK/INK/out/**IN_INK_GOOGLE_20200519.dat**\n-o/apps/tnk/in/download/in/**IN_INK_GOOGLE_20200519.dat**\n-uinnko1\n-end"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to pipe into sed as follows:

```
echo ... | sed -e 's/[.]dat.*/.dat/' -e 's|.*/||'
```

To use a "pure shell" solution try the # and % features of variable expansions:

```
e="-sIN.GOOGLE.IN.INK.INNK.INACC\n-i/am/ft/data/INK/out/GOOGLE_INK/INK/out/IN_INK_GOOGLE_20200519.dat\n-o/apps/tnk/in/download/in/IN_INK_GOOGLE_20200519.dat\n-uinnko1\n-end" 

f="${e%%.dat*}.dat";  #strip trailing clutter after first

echo ${f##*/};    #echo just name
echo IN_INK${f##*/IN_INK}  #variation
```